# CRUD on a entity with nested entity object

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Greeting all. I am kinda new in spring mvc. I have a`Student` entity, which has a`User` object as one to one relation. And `student-form.jsp` is my form to take input for creating  Student.

> Entity Class: Details skipped.

```
    public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer studentId;
    private String citizenship;
    private String nric;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    @OneToOne(optional = false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
}


  public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userId;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Student student;
}
```

> Spring Mvc Controller methods for showing the form.

```
 @RequestMapping("/student/new") //show blank student form
public ModelAndView showStudentFormNew() {
    Student s = new Student();
    User u = new User();
    s.setUser(u);
    ModelAndView v = new ModelAndView("crud/student-form");
    v.addObject("student", s);
    return v;
}
```

> Controller post request accept method when submit button is clicked in the form:

```
 @RequestMapping("/student/add") //add student to database
public ModelAndView addOrUpdateStudent(@ModelAttribute("student")    Student student) {

   // studentDao.save(student); // this doesnt work. 
    return getDebug(student.getUser().getFirstName()); //student.getuser() alwasy throws null pointer exception.   
}
```

> N.B `getDebug(string message)` returns debug page as ModelAndView
>
> So `user` in `Student` object is null here. even though I set the User in Student object before pass to the `student-form.jsp` `showStudentFormNew()` method, And if I uncomment the `//studentDao.save(student)` its give me a constraint violation exception as Student table doesn't have any UserID in its foreign key column. That means UserId in User table not generated automatically as its auto increment.
>
> `student-form.jsp:` page.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/student/add" method="post"  role="form" data-toggle="validator" >


            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <br></br>
                <label for="student.user.firstName" class="control-label col-xs-4">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.firstName" id="student.user.firstName" class="form-control" value="${student.user.firstName}" required="true"/>                                   

                <label for="student.user.lastName" class="control-label col-xs-4">Last Name:</label>                   
                <input type="text" name="student.user.lastName" id="student.user.lastName" class="form-control" value="${student.user.lastName}" required="true"/> 

                <label for="student.user.dob" class="control-label col-xs-4">Birth Date:</label>                 
                <input type="date"  name="lecturer.user.dob" id="student.user.dob" class="form-control" value="${student.user.dob}" placeholder="dd-MM-yyy" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.gender" class="control-label col-xs-4">Gender:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.gender" id="student.user.gender" class="form-control" value="${student.user.gender}" placeholder="male&female" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.citizenship" class="control-label col-xs-4">Citizenship:</label>                    
                <input type="text" name="student.citizenship" id="student.citizenship" class="form-control" value="${student.citizenship}" required="true"/> 

                <label for="student.nric" class="control-label col-xs-4">NRIC:</label>                   
                <input type="text" name="student.nric" id="student.nric" class="form-control" value="${student.nric}"  required="true"/>

                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <h2>Login Information</h2>
                <br></br>
                <input type="hidden" id="student.user.userId" name="student.user.userId" value="${student.user.userId}">

                <label for="student.user.userName" class="control-label col-xs-4">User Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.userName" id="student.user.userName" class="form-control" value="${student.user.userName}" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.password"  class="control-label col-xs-4">Password:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.password" id="student.user.password" class="form-control" value="${student.user.password}" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.phone"  class="control-label col-xs-4">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.phone" id="student.user.phone" class="form-control" value="${student.user.phone}" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.address"  class="control-label col-xs-4">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.address" id="student.user.address" class="form-control" value="${student.user.address}" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.email"  class="control-label col-xs-4">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.email" id="student.user.email" class="form-control" value="${student.user.email}" placeholder="student@gmail.com" required="true"/>


                <input type="hidden" name="student.user.role" id="student.user.role" class="form-control" value="student" required="true"/>

                <label for="student.user.status"  class="control-label col-xs-4">Status:</label>
                <input type="text" name="student.user.status" id="student.user.status" class="form-control" value="${student.user.status}" required="true"/>

                <br></br>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-md">Accept</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: How is id generated for Student entity. I don't see any `GeneratedValue` annotation on ` private Integer studentId;` in the `Student` class

Comment: It doesn't matter what objects you set on the way OUT.  The browser is responsible for building the objects when they come back IN.  You build the JSP, populated with all your data.  That displays in the browser.  Now all those objects mean nothing.  Only the FORM object in your page matters now. The browser POSTS back only what fields are in that form.  So what fields are in your JSP form?

Comment: yes GeneratedValue is there. I skipped to put here. sorry for that. @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu.

Comment: I updated my post with student-form.jsp. i used '@ModelAttribute.' As far as I know it should bind all the property accordingly. My edit page is working ok. I am using same form. Giving the Student object as ModelAtrribute. it shows all details. @Mr Spoon